# Сделать запрос sql с выводом количества по каждой записи из другой таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне нужно объединить три таблицы и получить следующую информацию. Имя пользователя, количество его лидов, и количество его лидов по каждому статусу из третей таблицы (статусов около 20)

```
users | leads          | lead_statuses
----- | -------------- | --------  
id    | id             | id        
name  | user_id        | name
      | lead_status_id |
        name
```

Пример что я хочу получить

```
User name | Count leads | Status 1 | Status 2 | Status 3  
user 1    | 20          | 5        |10        | 5
user 2    | 30          | 15       |5         | 10
user 3    | 5           | 1        |3         | 1
user 4    | 12          | 2        |8         | 2
```

Я написал следующий запрос:

```
SELECT 
   users.name as user_name,
   COUNT(leads.id) as count_leads,
   COUNT(if(lead_status.name = '1', 1, NULL)) as count_status_1,
   COUNT(if(lead_status.name = '2', 1, NULL)) as count_status_2,
   COUNT(if(lead_status.name = '3', 1, NULL)) as count_status_3
FROM users,
     leads,
     lead_statuses
WHERE users.id = leads.user_id AND
      leads.lead_status_id = lead_statuses.id
GROUP by user_name
```

Основная проблема в том, что нужно получить количество по всем статусом, вручную писать не особо хочется и статусы могут добиться. Есть варианты как можно это сделать?

Comment: PIVOT не реализован в MySQL. Используйте хранимую процедуру с динамическим SQL. См. напр. [SQL.ru: PIVOT средствами MySQL](https://www.sql.ru/forum/1293596/pivot-sredstvami-mysql).

Comment: Хотя я бы рекомендовал получить данные в формате `User - StatusNo - Count`, а формировать сводную таблицу уже на клиенте его средствами построения отчётов.